# Hide WordPress category unless user is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have the following code for my functions.php but it won't work how I want it to. I basically want it to hide the category unless the user is logged in, so basically redirect them to a login page

Code seems fine to me but wondering if there's any suggestions? I can't find ANY decent plugins to help me either

```
  add_action( 'init', 'check_redirect_page' );

function check_redirect_page() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_category( 177 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login' ) );
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code ..

```
!is_user_logged_in() && !is_category( 177 )
```

.. means *"If the user is not logged in and the category id is **NOT** 177"* .. and it seems you are asking how to check if the non-logged user **IS** on that category.
If that is the case, just remove the `!` in front of `is_category`.

Also, `template_redirect` might be a better hook to use.